# Hide MySQL count column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count, aggregate-functions

When you use count and group by in mysql, how do I hide the count column that implicitly shows up in the resulting table?

```
SELECT name, region, COUNT(*) as num_visits 
  FROM world
    GROUP BY region
      HAVING num_visits > 1
```

This will display a table with one column as the region and the other as the num_visits to each (given that it was visited more than once).

Is it possible to hide that last column so that only the regions are shown?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use the calculated column instead,

```
SELECT region
FROM   world
GROUP  BY region
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Ah okay so it counts at the end when it is already grouped rather than the start?

Comment: [SQL Query Order of Operations](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-SQL-Query-Order-of-Operations.htm)